# Parse Error in PHP Code unexpected T_CASE

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some issues with my code, and keep getting the same error, i have checked to make sure i have no open brackets or not forgotten to close a line.

The code below is only part of my whole code, this is lines 79-191 error is on line 109.

```
if(isset($id) && isset($_SESSION['user_current'])){

    switch($option) {               
        case 1:
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ebcs_albums` WHERE `id` = '{$_SESSION[user_current][2]}'");
            $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $img_ext = array('.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.gif'); 
            function getImages($dir) {
                global $img_path, $img_ext;
                $d = dir($img_path.$dir);  
                while (false !== ($file = $d->read())) {
                    $file_basename = substr($file, 0, strripos($file, '.'));
                    $file_basename = rename($file_basename,strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+/', '-', $file_basename)));
                    $file_ext = substr($file, strripos($file, '.'));
                    $file_ext = rename(strtolower($file_ext));
                    $file = $file_basename.$file_ext;
                    if(in_array($file_ext,$img_ext)) {
                        $images[] = array('file' => $file,'size' => getimagesize($file));
                    }
                }
                $d->close();
                asort($images);         
                return $images;
            }

            $array = getImages($result['Albums_Folder']);
            foreach ($array as $img) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ebcs_albums_temp` (`id`,`User`,`Image_Name`,`Image_Width`,`Image_Height`) 
                VALUES ('','$user','{$img[file]}','{$img[size][0]}','{$img[size][1]}')");
            }
            goto case 3;
            break;

        case 2:     
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ebcs_albums_temp` WHERE `User` = '{$_SESSION[user_current][0]}'");
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            foreach ($array as $remove) {
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ebcs_albums_temp` WHERE `id` = '{$remove[id]}'");
            }       
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ebcs_albums_users` WHERE `IP` = '{$_SESSION[user_current][0]}'");
            $id = $_SESSION['user_current'][2];
            unset($_SESSION['user_current']);   

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ebcs_albums_users` WHERE `Time` > '$inactive'");
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            foreach ($array as $remove) {
                $last = next($array)===false;
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ebcs_albums_users` WHERE `id` = '{$remove[id]}'");
                if(!$last){
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `ebcs_albums_temp` WHERE `User` = '{$remove[IP]}'");
                }
            }               
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'You have be logged out.';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=album.php?id=$id">';
            break;

        case 3:     
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT User FROM `ebcs_albums_temp`");
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            if(in_array($_SESSION['user_current'][0],$array)) {

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT Time FROM `ebcs_albums_users` WHERE `User` = '{$_SESSION[user_current][0]}'"); 
                    $mysql_time = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);    

                    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['user_current'][1];
                    $mysql_life = time() - $mysql_time['Time'];

                    if(($session_life > $inactive) || ($mysql_life > $inactive)){
                        goto case 2;    
                        break;
                    }

                    SmartyPaginate::connect();
                    SmartyPaginate::setLimit(24);
                    $query = sprintf("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `ebcs_albums_temp` WHERE `User` = '$user' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT %d,%d", SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(), SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
                    $results = mysql_query($query);                         
                        while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                            $images[] = array('file' => $x['Image_Name'],'width' => $x['Image_Width'],'height' => $x['Image_Height']);
                        }
                    $query = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total";
                    $_results = mysql_query($query);
                    $_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($_results);   
                    SmartyPaginate::setTotal($_row['total']);

                    SmartyPaginate::assign($smarty);    

                    $albums = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ebcs_albums` WHERE `id` = '{$_SESSION[user_current][2]}'");
                    $albums_arr = array();
                        while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums)) {
                            $albums_arr[] = $x;
                        }

                    $smarty->assign('id',$id);
                    $smarty->assign('images',$images);
                    $smarty->assign('albums_arr',$albums_arr);

                    include ("_header.php");    
                    $smarty->display('album_images.tpl');
                    include ("_footer.php");                
                    break;

            } else {
                goto case 1;    
                break;
            }
        default:    
            break;
    }
} else {                        
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'You are not logged in.';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=album.php?id=$id">';
}
```

Line 109 = goto case 3;
Line 110 = break;

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Goto. That's sick, Aaron.

Comment: I don't believe you can use `goto` and `case` together like that...

Comment: use functions for these kind of stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto is used within loops, not within cases/switches. You should use functions for this.

```
case 3:
   do_function_3();
   break;

function do_function_3(){
    // put the code here
}
```

Goto docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't use `goto` inside a switch. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php):

> You also cannot jump into any sort of loop or switch structure. You
>   may jump out of these, and a common use is to use a goto in place of a
>   multi-level break.

It looks like much of your functionality could be solved with functions rather than switch.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you see this syntax before?

You need either use [goto](http://bit.ly/uzmIfs) or [switch](http://bit.ly/uHSODL).

> You also cannot jump into any sort of loop or switch structure. You
>   may jump out of these, and a common use is to use a goto in place of a
>   multi-level break.

If you want to do this things in the way you architect you need to use loop there.

Have you ever tried to use ORM or frameworks? Where is this code goes from?

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect in so many ways. Hence the fix isn't simple. I tried to breakdown your code on my laptop by removing what's in each case replacing them with echos and leaving just the gotos.

If you really intended to use goto, here are some things you can start doing to remove the errors.

1. Start by removing the switch statement and control structs related to it like `default`, `break` etc.
2. Remove `case` after each "case" declaration replacing them with something like

   `a: // do stuff`
3. In each goto remove the case and do `goto a;`

Answer (score 0):

Dude, [GOTO is Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html). I'm getting a headache just trying to figure out what the heck you are trying to do.

Refactor your code, ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

It's an easy fix - don't use `;` use `:` instead.